# I am trying to build a GNOME extension for my personal use on my Ubuntu system

Tags: gnome-shell-extensions

I am trying to build a GNOME extension for my personal use on my Ubuntu system. The purpose of this extension is to switch between LAMP versions.

[image]

[image]

```
const Indicator = GObject.registerClass(
class Indicator extends PanelMenu.Button {
    _init() {
        super._init(0.0, _('PHP Switcher'));

        this.add_child(new St.Icon({
            icon_name: 'face-smile-symbolic',
            style_class: 'system-status-icon',
        }));

    
        let item = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_('Switch to PHP 7.4'));
        item.connect('activate', () => {
            GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop && sudo rm /opt/lampp && sudo ln -s 7.4 /opt/lampp && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start');
        });

        let item2 = new PopupMenu.PopupMenuItem(_('Switch to PHP 8.1'));
        item2.connect('activate', () => {
            GLib.spawn_command_line_sync('sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop && sudo rm /opt/lampp && sudo ln -s 8.1 /opt/lampp && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start');
        });

        this.menu.addMenuItem(item);
        this.menu.addMenuItem(item2);
    }
});
```

when i try click switch to php 7.4 and 8.1 its not work

Does anyone know why this isn't working?

Comment: Please don't paste images of code - paste the code itself in a code block.

Comment: Hello @AnyaShenanigans, I tried to add code, but it's not allowed; it's showing an error: It looks like your post is mostly code. Please add some more details.

Comment: How about you change your post so that it is not mostly code? E.g. by .... adding some details. You can describe your own thoughts, observation of symptoms, a prose description of the difference of the output you get and the output you want, ideally according to [ask]. Reading error messages is a skill you should hone with compilers as with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

Based on an image to text analysis of the input, we see the following commands being issued:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp stop && sudo rm /opt/lampp && sudo ln -s 7.4 /opt/lampp && sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Now this is being run in a shell extension. These don't have a terminal associated with them, and thus won't have a place to type in a password.

In general for things that are in this situation, you should use something other than `sudo`, such as `pkexec`, and make the entire set of commands into one `pkexec` command line like:

```
pkexec bash -c '/opt/lampp/lampp stop && rm /opt/lampp && ln -s 7.4 /opt/lampp && /opt/lampp/lampp start'
```

This will cause the prompt for the sudo password, and then run the set of commands.

So, for the full command line, as asked about in the subsequent comment:

```
GLib.spawn_command_line_sync("pkexec bash -c '/opt/lampp/lampp stop && rm /opt/lampp && ln -s 8.1 /opt/lampp && /opt/lampp/lampp start'");
```

*Please note*: testing this was really tedious as I could not get gnome to reload my extension without restarting my entire session.

Comment: like this :  GLib.spawn_command_line_sync("pkexec bash '/opt/lampp/lampp stop && rm /opt/lampp && ln -s 8.1 /opt/lampp && /opt/lampp/lampp start'"); ?

Comment: Similar for both, but don't forget the `-c` option for bash!

Comment: You'll probably want to see https://gjs.guide/guides/gio/subprocesses.html. A synchronous call is certainly the most straight-forward approach here, but in this case it's calling a D-Bus service which will try to schedule an asynchronous response in the process that's now being blocked.